# Convert hostnames to IP addresses in an Apache access log file

Tags: linux, apache

I want to be able to convert hostnames to IP addresses in an Apache access log file (i.e. the opposite of what logresolve does).

I have an accesslog file that has been converted with logresolve but I want to revert it.

Each line starts, as an example:

```
hostname.com - - [01/Jan/2016:00:00:00 +0000] "GET /stuff HTTP/1.1" 200 1046 "http://mywebsite.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1)"
```

How do I convert hostname.com to an IP address for every line?

Comment: What have you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963085/linux-command-to-translate-domainname-to-ip

Comment: Check this http://serverfault.com/questions/618037/how-to-do-a-reverse-dns-lookup-on-my-apache-logs

Comment: I want to do the opposite of logresolve on an accesslog file which has over 10000 lines.  Looking up each hostname manually would take a very long time, I want to script it somehow.